# cant figure out display inline?

Tags: html, css

ok the code is listed below, and when I adjust the css as follows:

```
.Nav {
color:red;
float:left;
display:inline;}
```

It wont display inline? What Am I doing wrong? Im sure this is a stupid question.

```
<head></head>

<body>
    <div class="Nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Sign Up</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to put `display: inline` on the li elements.

Comment: Should this not be on the li elements? http://jsfiddle.net/htaakkzw/

Comment: Floated items are automatically block-level elements.

Answer (score 1):

dont use float and dislay inline at the same time just use `

```
display:inline-block;
```

and it will work perfectly fine

i would also recommend you to read this article, it's a short article but helps a lot
[click this to read the article](https://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/)
atleast it did help me a lot and cleared my concepts of float and display

Answer (score 0):

The `div` itself is displayed inline, but since it's the only element inside the `body`, it has no visible effect.

You need to set it on the li elements:

**CSS**

```
div.nav ul li {
    float: left; /* All li elements inside the div.nav are floated to left... */
    display: inline; /* ...and displayed inline – but it does not make sence,
        since a floating element cannot be inline. */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        ...
```

Comment: If you use float:left on a inline element, the element basically becomes a display: block element.

Comment: Yes, that's right, `inline` cannot be used with `float`.

Comment: What does "Instead, use the position property" mean? To achieve what?

Comment: @Alohci The `position` property defines the positioning of the element in context by whether it's floating or not. But in most cases, it's not necessary to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It will.  Your div is the one with the .Nav class so that div will be displayed inline.  Try:

```
.Nav li{
  display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/3fo1thex/)

```
.Nav ul li{
color:red;
display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put display: inline on li elements, all they will be on a unique line.

**As you can see here:** http://jsfiddle.net/b31krn9b/

CSS:

```
.Nav {
    color:red;
    float:left;
}
.Nav li {
    display:inline;
}
```

---

Another ways to align:

1. Using float: http://jsfiddle.net/b31krn9b/1/
2. Or even display: inline-block (this is better because you can use margin-right and left): http://jsfiddle.net/b31krn9b/2/